# Error retrieving Youtube comments using youtube.commentThreads().list() - Python

Tags: exception, error-handling, comments, youtube-data-api, httpresponse

I am trying to retrieve comments from multiple videos and if the video have comments restricted, it throws me error on response. How can I handle this?
Example for the video with comment session restricted:

```
video_Id= 'zO-jDWZ4mxA'
video_response = youtube.commentThreads().list(
 part = 'snippet',
 videoId = video_Id).execute()
video_response
```

Error:

```
HttpError: <HttpError 404 when requesting https://youtube.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/commentThreads?part=snippet&videoId=zO-jDWZ4mxA&key=AIzaSy...&alt=json returned "The video identified by the <code><a href="/youtube/v3/docs/commentThreads/list#videoId">videoId</a></code> parameter could not be found.". Details: "[{'message': 'The video identified by the <code><a href="/youtube/v3/docs/commentThreads/list#videoId">videoId</a></code> parameter could not be found.', 'domain': 'youtube.commentThread', 'reason': 'videoNotFound', 'location': 'videoId', 'locationType': 'parameter'}]">
```

Comment: Please remove your API key. Please add Python tag since it is a python related question. Note: your video id is a non unvailable video for random people so I guess you use OAuth2 but we don't have your access to this video so we can't easily reproduce your problem. If this Python error stops your program then have a look to try/exception in Python.

Comment: Thank you @BenjaminLoison. I have handled it with try/exception and it worked as I expected.